# Sql datasource wizard problem

Tags: sql, datasource, wizard

hi guys i have an error with sqldatasource.

When i click sqldatasource's updatequery property visual studio give an error:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\%DXROOT%\ProductionTools\BuildComponents.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

what's this? How I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing the Installation sounds like a good idea.

Also have you tried searcing for the file **BuildComponents.dll**.  If you can find it, try copying it to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\%DXROOT%\ProductionTools folder and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should do a "Repair" installation of Visual Studio.